# What are the test description conventions in Flutter and Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, automated-tests

It seems to me that developers should have resources to some basic and general principles about how to write an appropriate description to a test. Should it be long? Short? Should it include numbers? Operations? And so on...

```
void main() {
  //The first argument is the description I mean
  test('Counter value should be incremented', () {
    final counter = Counter();

    counter.increment();

    expect(counter.value, 1);
  });
}
```

I haven't found anything about it in the docs. For reference:

[Effective Dart: Style](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design)

[Effective Dart: Design](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design)

[Dart testing](https://dart.dev/guides/testing)

[An introduction to unit testing](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction)

Is this then completely open? If so, and answer confirming that this is the case would also be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common convention I've seen is something like this:

```
group('Class/method to be tested', () {
    test('should x when y', () {
        // Test that object meets criteria x when condition y is met.
    });

    test('should p when q', () {
        // Test that object meets criteria p when condition q is met.
    });
});
```

For a more concrete (albeit contrived) example:

```
group('+ operator', () {
    test('should return sum of arguments when called with valid number arguments', () {
        // ...
    });

    test('should throw exception when invalid arguments are passed', () {
        // ...
    });
});
```